# Xamarin Forms IOS Remove IconImageSource

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, xamarin.ios

ToolbarItems with IconImageSource are causing my app to crash on iOS. So I am willing to remove them only on iOS but show the icons on Android. How Can I do that? Thank you!

```
<TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="searchOptn" IconImageSource="{local:ImageResource Bufib.Logos.search.png}" Clicked="searchOptn_Clicked" />
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="syncOptn" IconImageSource="{local:ImageResource Bufib.Logos.sync.png}" Clicked="syncOptn_Clicked"/>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="favouriteOptn" Clicked="favouriteOptn_Clicked" Order="Secondary"/>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="visibilityOptn" Clicked="visibilityOptn_Clicked"  Order="Secondary"/>
</TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6387

Comment: no one seems to have a clear answer. @Jason

Comment: "The issue will be fixed by #14749 and we will include it in SR7."

Comment: Ideas to try in the meantime. I haven't tested, but try adding a first ToolbarItem, without an icon, with `IsVisible="False"`.  If that doesn't help, then the best I can think of is to let it be visible, but with blank text and no icon - make it not very noticeable. Maybe also can set `WidthRequest` or a very small `FontSize`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thank u for the time but taht did not work, I accepted the answer that worked for,

Comment: @Jason thank u also for ur time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xamarin.Forms, using `Device.RuntimePlatform` can be used to obtain the mobile phone platform used by the current user.

Judgment and data processing by using the above code.

Here is my background code for your reference:

```
public partial class TabbedPage1 : TabbedPage
{
    public TabbedPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == "Android")//Determine whether it is Android, if it is, add a picture
        {
            mytest.IconImageSource = "xxx.jpg";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great, I dunno how I missed this solution. Thank u!